# How can I download a deployable program from mainnet?

Tags: solana-program, solana-test-validator

I'm building a Solana SDK and I have a few integration tests that need [SPL Programs](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library) that are running against live clusters (mainnet or devnet). However, I'd like to use a local testnet using [testcontainers](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-node) which works fine so far, as I'm running the container passing a few `--clone` which copy the data I need.

The problem is that one of the tests requires sending a transaction to create a DAO, using the governance program, which doesn't seem to come out of the box in the test validator. As a result, the test fails saying that it attempted to load a program that doesn't exist (this actually means it's not found by bpf loader). A possible fix to this is to checkout the program code (in my specific case I need the tag `tags/governance-v2.2.6`), run `cargo build-bpf` and pass the option `--bpf-program GovER5Lthms3bLBqWub97yVrMmEogzX7xNjdXpPPCVZw ./spl_governance.so` when I run the test validator. I tried this and it works.

However, I'd like to avoid my workaround and download the `.so` into a file programatically, and instantiate the `solana-test-validator` pointing to that file. I know it's possible to download some executable data (from [here](https://explorer.solana.com/address/GovER5Lthms3bLBqWub97yVrMmEogzX7xNjdXpPPCVZw) if you navigate to it's [executable data account](https://explorer.solana.com/address/BZYjZ2ZbtAawP9WPt5yXszcoMWTvNFFX4AMbnDojtSGL)) in a bin format. I don't know how to proceed from here, is it possible to get `.so` code from a bin executable? Should I just copy the `bin` file into my test ledger folder?

Hope the context and problem are clear. Any guidance will be helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options.

If you want to dump the *.so for a particular program, you can do:

```
solana config set -um # be sure you're on mainnet
solana program dump GovER5Lthms3bLBqWub97yVrMmEogzX7xNjdXpPPCVZw spl_governance.so
```

Otherwise, you can use the `--clone` option for programs as well when instantiating your test validator:

```
solana-test-validator --clone GovER5Lthms3bLBqWub97yVrMmEogzX7xNjdXpPPCVZw -um
```

Comment: `--clone GovER5Lthms3bLBqWub97yVrMmEogzX7xNjdXpPPCVZw` copies the account data to the test ledger, but it doesn't load the program into the bpf. 

`solana program dump` works great. Thanks!

Comment: ah my bad, that's right, you'll also need to clone `BZYjZ2ZbtAawP9WPt5yXszcoMWTvNFFX4AMbnDojtSGL` if you want to go that route

Comment: Would you elaborate more on that? What is `BZYjZ2ZbtAawP9WPt5yXszcoMWTvNFFX4AMbnDojtSGL`?

Comment: That's the program data account. You'll see it as the "Executable Data Account" at https://explorer.solana.com/address/GovER5Lthms3bLBqWub97yVrMmEogzX7xNjdXpPPCVZw